# Combination of ID2D1PathGeometry and ID2D1DeviceContext

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

My goal is to draw a geometry path in a render target provided by a `ID2D1DeviceContext`.
I have an `ID2D1Factory` created by `D2D1CreateFactory` and the following code fails:

```
CComPtr<ID2D1PathGeometry> m_pPathGeometry;
fa->CreatePathGeometry(&m_pPathGeometry);

CComQIPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> b;
D2D1_COLOR_F cc = { 1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f };
pRT->CreateSolidColorBrush(cc, &b);
pRT->FillGeometry(m_pPathGeometry, b);
```

When calling pRT->EndDraw(), I get a message `0x88990012 : Objects used together must be created from the same factory instance`.

Why ? Does that mean that the path geometry is only compatible with a render target created with `fa->CreateHwndRenderTarget()` ? But I need of course a ID2D1DeviceContext for rendering into a bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My crystal ball tells me that you are creating `ID2D1DeviceContext` instance by invoking `D2D1CreateDeviceContext` function which also creates a new factory object and then you create another factory by invoking `D2D1CreateFactory` function causing created objects to be incompatible. So instead of creating another factory you should query factory corresponding to device context using `ID2D1Resource::GetFactory`.